# i am trying to read username and password from an excel file, but it is showing errors at the sendkeys method

Tags: selenium-webdriver

public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {

```
    WebDriver wd=new FirefoxDriver();
 wd.navigate().to("http://www.gmail.com");
  Object[][] Arr=new Object[4][2];
 InputStream fi=new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\harini.b\\Desktop\\excel.xlsx");
 Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(fi);
 Sheet s=wb.getSheetAt(0);
 int row=s.getLastRowNum();
 System.out.println("no of rows: "+row);
 for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
 {
    Row r=s.getRow(i+1);
    int col=r.getLastCellNum();
    for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
        Cell c=r.getCell(j);
        if(c.getCellType()==c.CELL_TYPE_STRING){
            Arr[i][j]=c.getStringCellValue();

        }else if(c.getCellType()==c.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC){
            Arr[i][j]=c.getNumericCellValue();

        }

        wd.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys(Arr[i][0]);
        wd.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys(Arr[0][j]);
    }
 }
```

I am using poi jar files
This is my code, how can i get excel multiple data to gmail login page
Thanks in Advance

Regards
srinu

Answer (score 0):

Your array 'Arr' is a 'java.lang.Object' array.

`Object[][] Arr=new Object[4][2];`

The method 'sendKeys' requires a charSequence. The compiler must tell you something like "The method sendKeys(CharSequence...) in the type WebElement is not applicable for the arguments (Object)".

Ensure your spreadsheet contains only string values and declare your array as 'java.lang.String'.